# What does 23:16 refer to with error "manifest.json:23:16: duplicate key"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, key, manifest.json

I tried uploading a zip file of my first Chrome extension in my Chrome Developer console. The extension works great locally on my Chrome browser in developer mode, so I thought all I had to do was zip it and upload it to the developer console. But I am getting an error when I try to upload it to the developer console: "manifest.json:23:16: duplicate key."

What do the 23 and 16 refer to? I was thinking line 23 and 16 characters in on line 23 but that does not make any sense when I look at line 23 of my manifest.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out, and yes the error was telling me the line number. It turns out I had duplicate "permissions" keys for storage. I deleted one of them. I think it should all be okay now.

My manifest.json file had duplicate "permissions", like this:

```
 "permissions": ["storage"],
 "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
    ],
```